# How to add image in jlist

Tags: java, swing, jlist, imageicon

Hi  i have created a j list and there i want to add an image before any text in that text  how can i do this i tried but i am not able to achieve my goal i want to add an image before list element"Barmer".

```
    public class ListDemo extends JPanel
                          implements ListSelectionListener {
        private JList list;
        private DefaultListModel listModel;


        public ListDemo() {
            super(new BorderLayout());

            listModel = new DefaultListModel();
            listModel.addElement("Barmer");
           //Create the list and put it in a scroll pane.
            list = new JList(listModel);
            list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            list.setSelectedIndex(0);
            list.addListSelectionListener(this);
            list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
            list.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0,191,255));;
           list.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,35));
            list.setForeground( Color.white );
            list.setFixedCellHeight(60);
    list.setFixedCellWidth(50);
    list.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,20, 20, 20));


            JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
            add(listScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        }
         public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

        }

        private static void createAndShowGUI() {
            //Create and set up the window.
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("ListDemo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            //Create and set up the content pane.
            JComponent newContentPane = new ListDemo();
            newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
            frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
           frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    frame.setUndecorated(true);

            //Display the window.
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }



          public static void main(String[] args) {

                    createAndShowGUI();

        }
    }
```

How can i do this help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please a) find the 'format my code' shortcut in your IDE **and use it.** b) Actually go through the tutorials before expecting us to spoon feed information to you.  The first hit for 'jlist tutorial' shows exactly how to do it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a matter easily answered by going through the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want to look as a custom `ListCellRenderer`. You can look at [Provding a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for `JComboBox`. It the same for a `JList`. The tutorial over-complicates a bit for simple scenarios. They extends `JLabel` and `implements ListCellRender` where you have to implement a few unnecessary things if you just want basic functionality but with am image.

You can just instead `extends` or create a anonymous `DefaultListCellRender` and just get the `JLabel` render component and add to it, like setting `Font` and `ImageIcon`. Something like this

```
public class MarioListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    Font font = new Font("helvitica", Font.BOLD, 24);

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        label.setIcon(imageMap.get((String) value));
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.RIGHT);
        label.setFont(font);
        return label;
    }
}
```

What happens is that each cell uses this renderer and calls the `getListCellRendererComponent` method. The `value` you see passed to the method is the value in each cell, in my case, one of the character names in the list. I then map that to the corresponding `ImageIcon` and set the `Icon` on the `JLabel` renderer component.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MarioList {

    private final Map<String, ImageIcon> imageMap;

    public MarioList() {
        String[] nameList = {"Mario", "Luigi", "Bowser", "Koopa", "Princess"};
        imageMap = createImageMap(nameList);
        JList list = new JList(nameList);
        list.setCellRenderer(new MarioListRenderer());

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class MarioListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        Font font = new Font("helvitica", Font.BOLD, 24);

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                JList list, Object value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                    list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            label.setIcon(imageMap.get((String) value));
            label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.RIGHT);
            label.setFont(font);
            return label;
        }
    }

    private Map<String, ImageIcon> createImageMap(String[] list) {
        Map<String, ImageIcon> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (String s : list) {
            map.put(s, new ImageIcon(
                    getClass().getResource("/marioscaled/" + s + ".png")));
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MarioList();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Side Note**

- AndrewThompson is correct about just checking the tutorial first. You could have easily found an example implementation, then tried it out. Swing tutorials can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). Look under the Using Swing Components for how to use different components.
- Swing apps should be run on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). You can do so by wrapping your `creatAndShowGui()` in a `SwinUtilities.invokeLater...`. See more at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

---

**UPDATE** with internet images.

[image][image][image][image][image]

new Code

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MarioList {

    private final Map<String, ImageIcon> imageMap;

    public MarioList() {
        String[] nameList = {"Mario", "Luigi", "Bowser", "Koopa", "Princess"};
        imageMap = createImageMap(nameList);
        JList list = new JList(nameList);
        list.setCellRenderer(new MarioListRenderer());

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(list);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class MarioListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        Font font = new Font("helvitica", Font.BOLD, 24);

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                JList list, Object value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
                    list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            label.setIcon(imageMap.get((String) value));
            label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.RIGHT);
            label.setFont(font);
            return label;
        }
    }

    private Map<String, ImageIcon> createImageMap(String[] list) {
        Map<String, ImageIcon> map = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            map.put("Mario", new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCsHu.png")));
            map.put("Luigi", new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvHN4.png")));
            map.put("Bowser", new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/s89ON.png")));
            map.put("Koopa", new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEK2o.png")));
            map.put("Princess", new ImageIcon(new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4T4l.png")));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MarioList();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: dear i am compiling your program  giving exception

Comment: You need to use your own images, My images paths will not work for you.

Comment: Hold on, I will fix it, so you can use the same images from the internet

Comment: i am using my image path   E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable   in plce of /marioscaled/

Comment: That's not an embeded resources path, so you cant use `getClass().getResource()`

Comment: Try out the new code. Also look at how to use [embedded-resources](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/2587435)

Comment: i want to set word Mario on the top

Comment: If you want it on top of the image, just use `label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP); label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);`

Comment: Thanks it work   but now i am trying to draw line between every image so  nothing is drawing over there

Comment: I don't get what you mean?

Comment: between  every  image i want to draw a line i updated  where  my code

Comment: Try this `label.setBorder(new MatteBorder( 0, 0, 1, 0, Color.GRAY));`

Comment: after mario shoukd draw a line then after luigi should draw a line .... like this i want

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49293/discussion-between-user3377703-and-peeskillet)